# IE + VLC Web Plugin Issue

Tags: canvas, vlc

In HTML5, we are using VLC web plugin to display live streaming video. We have placed HTML canvas over the video plugin for drawing few shapes like rectangle. In case of internet explorer the rectangle drawn moves behind the VLC Video plugin. The same code works correctly in case of Firefox. Can anyone please help us out in the same?

Below is the sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>IE VLC Canvas Issue</title>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #displayPlugin
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        #navi
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        #navi
        {
            z-index: 1000;
        }
        #displayPlugin
        {
            z-index: 0;
        }
        body
        {
            font-size: 11.2px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="">
    <div id="containerDiv">
        <div id="navi" style="background-color: transparent">
            <canvas id='drawingCanvas' width='640' height='480'></canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="displayPlugin">
            <object id="playerId" classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921' toolbar='false'
                controls='false' width='640' height='480' events='True'>
                <param name='AutoPlay' value='true' />
                <param name='ShowDisplay' value='true' />
                <param name='Controls' value='false' />
                <param name='Toolbar' value='false' />
                <param name='windowless' value='true' />
                <param name='wmode' value='transparent' />
                <param name='Src' value='rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov' />
                <embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' progid='VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2' name='video1'
                    id='video1' autoplay='yes' wmode='transparent' windowless='true' controls='false'
                    loop='yes' width='640' height='480' target='rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov'
                    pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' />
            </object>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script language="javascript">
    var c = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
</script>

</html>
```

Thanks,
Jaymin Shah